# ASP.NET Web Pages convert simple SQL Select to Razor 2.2

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

I need feedback from expert ASP.NET Razor web programmers.  I am fairly experienced in Visual Studio on the database end, but apparently my web programming skills are 8 years outdated by my Google results.  I want to convert very basic ASP.NET Web Pages code to the new ASP.NET Razor Pages 2.2, but it appears I'll have to create models, controllers and views.  This may be the only way, but I find it hard to believe Microsoft would make something simple like ASP.NET Web Pages so much more complicated with Razor.

I wrote the code very basic below since I can expand on your answer, but I will have three SQL joins in my Razor page, and the database view I'm pulling from already has 6 foreign keys joined in the database so the scaffolding features are causing confusion in views when I use the pre-built Razor pages.  My project is read only from db so CRUD functionality is not needed.

Here is how simply I accomplished this task in the old Microsoft Web Pages software. Is there an equally simple way to reproduce the following result in Razor Pages or will I need to use the built in MVC functions of Razor 2.2?

```
@using WebMatrix.Data
@using System.Data.SqlClient
@{
    var DB = Database.Open("WebConfigDBName");
}
<html>
<body>
    @{
        var result = DB.Query("SELECT A.columnA AS columnA, B.columnB AS columnB from TableAName AS A LEFT OUTER JOIN TableBName AS B ON A.id = B.id");
    }
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th>columnA</th>
            <th>columnB</th>
        </tr>
        @foreach (var row in result)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>@row.columnA</td>
                <td>@row.columnB</td>
            </tr>
        }
    </table>
</body>
</html>
@{
    DB.Close();
}
```

Comment: The view being responsible for SQL transactions really blows up the separation of concerns that MVC is built on. I would not recommend doing this.

Comment: Thanks Jonathon.  I'm new to MVC so that helps my understanding a little.  My knowledge from years ago was create a 'view' in the database itself to keep from exposing the database tables to the internet, but I see you're explanation is expecting the view portion of MVC to protect the tables.  Good feedback.

Comment: You may be conflating the meaning of a 'view' in context of a relational database vs a view in the context of the MVC architecture.

Answer (score 0):

Update - I didn’t find an easy answer to my question so I’m taking a minute to update this post.  The only help that made life easier was the PowerShell “Scaffold-DbContext” command in the following Microsoft Note; found under the Reverse engineer your model section:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/get-started/aspnetcore/existing-db?view=aspnetcore-2.2

This Scaffold-DbContext command developed models for me which saved a good bit of work.  After models were created, I was able to build CRUD pages in ASP.NET CORE 2.2 (steps found in same MS note) then wrote a lot of modifications since I built the site around 12 existing SQL Server tables.  I ended up editing every model and its context in addition to editing most all the scaffolding so my code is all custom now.

I am trying to cross-train someone who knows nothing about ASP.NET CORE so I’m still open to replies if someone else finds an easier solution.